# How to insert multiple rows from a data array in a Doctrine migration?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, doctrine, doctrine-migrations

I have created an Entity and generated the migration file. Now, I want to insert some data into the table in the MySQL database when doing the migration.

My `up` function is as follows.

```
public function up(Schema $schema) : void
{
  $data = array(
    'My Data 1',
    'My Data 2',
    'My Data 3',
  );

  $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() !== 'mysql', 'Migration can only be executed safely on \'mysql\'.');

  $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE my_table (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` ENGINE = InnoDB');

  $this->addSql('INSERT INTO my_table (name) VALUES (?)', $data, \PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
```

I want to add all data in the `$data` array to `my_data` table. All elements in the `$data` array are strings.

When I run `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate`, it gives the following error.

```
Argument 3 passed to Doctrine\Migrations\AbstractMigration::addSql() must be of the type array, int given...
```

How to fix this error and achieve what I want?

Comment: Check out the [signature of `addSql`](https://github.com/doctrine/migrations/blob/3.0.x/lib/Doctrine/Migrations/AbstractMigration.php#L143).

Comment: You might also want to take a look at an [example](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-migrations/en/3.0/reference/migration-classes.html#addsql) of usage.

Comment: @El_Vanja Thank you for your comments. I managed to achieve what I wanted. I acknowledged you in my answer. :)

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to achieve what I wanted as follows... This answer is inspired by the resources commented on my question by @El_Vanja.

```
public function up(Schema $schema) : void
{
  $data = array(
    'My Data 1',
    'My Data 2',
    'My Data 3',
  );

  $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() !== 'mysql', 'Migration can only be executed safely on \'mysql\'.');

  $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE my_table (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` ENGINE = InnoDB');

  foreach($data as $d) {
    $this->addSql('INSERT INTO my_table (name) VALUES (?)', array($d));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very late to the party, but perhaps this will help someone in the future. Using an [associative array](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_associative.asp) as input for the query described in [Sennen Randika' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65072063) will not work and throws the following error: `Positional parameter at index 0 does not have a bound value.`

So do **not** use an array structure as below:

```php
  $data = array(
    'key1' => 'My Data 1',
    'key2' => 'My Data 2',
    'key3' => 'My Data 3',
  );
```

Comment: This should have been a comment on the referenced answer.